# Youtube WatchMe android project Login issue

Tags: android, ffmpeg, youtube-api, apk, live-streaming

I created live streaming application using https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme. And its installed on android phone.If I logged into this app.I's still shows the "Not Signed in" Message. After login its showing the following error in android studio console

```
09-16 16:48:01.970   25937-3107/com.google.android.apps.watchme E/WatchMe﹕ com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
    {
    "code": 403,
    "errors": [
    {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
    }
    ],
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
    }
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.util.YouTubeApi.getLiveEvents(YouTubeApi.java:155)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.MainActivity$GetLiveEventsTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:312)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.MainActivity$GetLiveEventsTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:295)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

How can i solve this issue please help.

This application is connecting to `YouTube Watch Me` project.Is it possible to connect my project using client Id and client secret(How can i configure my client id to this app?)?

Please suggest

Comment: he API (YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project

Comment: I didn't configured any project for this watchme app. But still i am getting this error? How can i configure my project client id to this project?

Comment: have u know about google console in android

Comment: google console in android?

Comment: To use this application,In your Google Developers Console,
Enable the `YouTube Data API v3` and `Google+ API`.
Create a `client ID` for Android, using your `SHA1 and package name`. And other steps are listed [here](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/blob/master/README.md).